# What's the best way to remember instance variables in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic class in `react` that draws a rectangle when I click

```
Conq.R.Canvas = React.createClass

  displayName: 'Canvas'

  componentDidMount: ->
    @setState $(@getDOMNode()).offset()

  onMouseDown: (e) ->

    canvas = @getDOMNode()
    context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.fillRect e.clientX - @state.left, e.clientY - @state.top, 10, 10

  render: ->

    <canvas onMouseDown={@onMouseDown}></canvas>
```

It works fine.  Is it typical to store things like `offset` in state, or should I just set it to `this` or put it in `props`?  What's the convention and why?

Don't knock me for storing it, if it wasn't offset, it could be some other value that I store.  My basic question is where do I put local variables that are only used within an instance, and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be state/props if changing it causes either:

- render to output a different result
- componentWillUpdate to behave differently
- componentDidUpdate to behave differently

In this case `this.top` would be fine.

Comment: As a sub-bullet to "render to output a different result", I'd add "is depended on by a child component". Otherwise thumbs up.

Comment: That would be a different result, because you're rendering a child component with different props.  `<a href={this.state.url} />` and `<foo bar={this.state.baz} />` are different results when the state changes.

Comment: Not sure I follow? `<a>` is a component as well, it's a `React.DOM.a`.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant. I mentioned to add it as a sub-bullet for clarity, although its end result might ultimately match the first bullet if it causes a descendant to render differently. In the interest of encapsulation, a parent component shouldn't "know" the effect of changing the values it passes to its descendants so I thought it'd be worth calling out.